# Solutions for adding bi-directional web API to winforms application

Tags: .net, webapi

I am hoping this is the right place to ask such a question. I have an application that interacts with a piece of hardware via USB HID. This application has served its purpose well but we have a constant need to add little 'script' like pieces of code to it to automate various tasks.

What we have decided to try is adding a web based API to the application that we can send commands to and receive events from. The idea then is to use GET or PUSH requests in something like python to create these simple little device test scripts as we need them.

The questions I have are around whether this is even the right way to go about it or is there something better? And if this is the right way to go about it, how do we handle the events that come back from the device that need to be sent to the script somehow? I understand you can use things like webhooks or SSE but I am not really familiar enough with these to make a good choice on what to use in this instance.

At present I am looking at things like OWIN for an internal web server but I could be completely off track. Have done a lot of google'ing on this and I am not really seeing a clear best or right way. Any suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds very similar to an application I built a while ago. We had USB cash drawers that needed to be controlled and monitored from a web application. The solution was to build a small shim application that could interact with the local hardware. We used ASP.NET SignalR. https://dotnet.microsoft.com/apps/aspnet/signalr

Essentially how it works is that the local code and the webserver can have a bidirectional communication channel. This enables the web server to push commands or request data from the locally running code. The local code doesn't need to run a web server. In fact, it's very little code to get it up and running.

I'd recommend that you take a look at SignalR. If you have any further questions, feel free to ask!

Comment: OK so the application that will need to run the server in this case and then talk to the device is a .NET 4.6.1 application. From what I can see you should be using .NET Core 5.0 for the latest version of SignalR but there are older versions. Updating the app could be an issue at this point. Do you have any further suggestions on how to handle this?